# Как правильно обращаться к полю в таблице postgresql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, psql, postgresql9.6

На сервисе [ElephantSQL](https://api.elephantsql.com/) создал бд

PostgreSQL version  9.6.5

```
CREATE TABLE Coins (name VARCHAR(30), last_update VARCHAR(30), price numeric(50,50));
```

Проверяем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее еще 1 проверка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ошибка возникает когда пытаюсь обратиться: `SELECT * FROM Coins WHERE name="ETHBTC";`

```
No rows returned
ERROR:  column "ETHBTC" does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT * FROM Coins WHERE name="ETHBTC";
                                   ^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В двойных кавычках записывается имя колонки. Естественно, в таблице такой колонки нет. Для строкового литерала используйте одинарные кавычки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov думаю, можно перенести это в ответ.